# Python produces: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application, but only with activate_this.py

Tags: python, virtualenv

This is presumably the same as [Python produces: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021614/python-produces-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) However, that has no answers, and I have additional details for my situation.

Background:

I'm using a venv, it gets activated internally with `activate_this.py` via:

```
exec(compile(open(venv_script, "rb").read(), venv_script, 'exec'), dict(__file__=venv_script))
```

This worked on python2 at least...

when I import numpy I get:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

If I activate the venv normally, I can import numpy fine, so I'm guessing the problem is how I'm using `activate_this.py`...

Minimal case:

```
C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>virtualenv testEnv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\brianp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32'
New python executable in C:\DROPBO~1\venvs\testEnv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>testEnv\Scripts\activate

(testEnv) C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/be/b4d697563d4a211596a350414a87612204a8bb987c4c1b34598cd4904f55/numpy-1.16.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.2

(testEnv) C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>deactivate
C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> this_file = 'testenv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
>>> exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\testenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\testenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>> exit()

C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>testEnv\Scripts\activate

(testEnv) C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: Add a `print(sys.executable)` before the error and paste the output

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What would make it complete? It's pretty minimal... I open python, type the stuff in the big block, and get the error...

Comment: "NameError: name 'venv_script' is not defined" -- Please read that link that was provided. People shouldn't have to guess what other parts look like or guess which parts are relevant. Preferably start from an empty directory where you set up your venv. Of course, provided setting up a venv is necessary at all, which is your job to find out before posting here.

Comment: I mean, it's a virtualenv with numpy.  I included the entire script of creating the venv, and the thing happening.

Comment: Added successful import after activating at the command line rather than inside python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known error: it's an architecture mismatch *032bit* / *064bit* (*pc032* / *pc064*), in your case trying to load a *032bit* *.dll* in a *064bit* process. To make things clear, *NumPy* contains a bunch of *.dll*s that get loaded in the current process when importing it.
It's actually a **duplicate** of [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546), but I'm going to detail.

The examples in the question are twisted and hard to read: some example that works, then some that doesn't then some that works again and so on (for example I don't even know what's the 2<sup>nd</sup> snippet purpose), instead of clearly separating scenarios that do work from those that don't.

Anyway in spite of the above, I was able to identify the problem.

- The *testEnv* environment that you created (and installed *NumPy* in) is ***pc032***:

  - 3<sup>rd</sup> snippet (begin):

    > ```
    > Using base prefix
    > 'c:\\users\\brianp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32'
    > ```
  - 3<sup>rd</sup> snippet (end):

    > ```
    > Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    > ```
  - In this case, `import numpy` works (and ***NumPy*** (and the *.dll*s that it contains) is ***pc032***)
- The *Python* interpreter launched from **outside** *testEnv* is ***pc064***:

  - 3<sup>rd</sup> snippet (mid):

    > ```
    > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    > ```
  - When running *testEnv*'s *activate_this.py* in the current process, it adds *testEnv* paths to *%PYTHONPATH%* (*sys.path*), and `import numpy` picks the *pc032* version from *testEnv*, which obviously fails

To get rid of this error you can either (listing some of the possible options):

1. Use a *pc032* *Python* from outside *VEnv* (*C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\python*)
2. The other way around: create a *testEnv64* *VEnv*, and use its *activate_this.py*
3. Don't use *activate_this.py* at all, unless you know what you're doing (I'd recommend this one)

Might also want to check [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546).

Answer (score -1):

Another thing might have happened. `VS code` automatically searches for the numpy and other packages from predefined OS locations. It might have found out `32 bit` version of `numpy` instead of a `64 bit` version.
Fix:
Uninstall `numpy` from all OS locations
* In `VS code terminal`. Type `pip uninstall numpy` or `conda uninstall numpy` (If you use `Anaconda`)
* Restart VS code
* Voila! (Reinstall numpy if the problem persists)

Comment: "*Fix: Uninstall `numpy` from all OS locations*": that's **bad advice** (should be avoided) and may lead to messing up other environments, instead of focusing on solving the actual problem.