# Unable To Import Python Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When I installed arcade in my Windows using pip and I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcade
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\arcade\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .window_commands import close_window
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\arcade\window_commands.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I am a beginner so kindly help in simple phrases

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error: OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512907/python-error-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this.

1. Make sure your environment is clean. Meaning you have installed everything correctly.
2. I can see you're using python3.8 version. If you are using Python 3.8, the “Numpy” and “Pillow” libraries might try to build themselves from scratch, which will probably error out. To fix, we can manually update “pip” by opening a a PyCharm terminal, and then typing the following into the terminal:

   ```
   python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
   ```

   for details you can refer:
   https://arcade.academy/installation_windows.html